# Advanced log wrapper for Android

Tags: android, logging

I am looking to have a Log wrapper in Android that can give me following:
- File logging
- Logging on/off at runtime
- Logging based on release/dev version.
- Code available (not lib).

Can you please suggest some :).

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look here: https://github.com/vinay-choudhary/logwrapper/

This is a logging utility I had written some time ago. It will provide you file logging based on tags you use for logging. Also you can enable/disable logging in runtime. It doesnt have logging based on release/dev versions :(

Comment: Nice utility. Was going with log4j but will try yours as you provide logging to files based on tags :). I was looking for turning off logs from some tags. But it will be helpful if you can provide API to set default log levels.